# Segmentation fault on function

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, sdl

I'm learning how to use SDL library to graphic programming and I am having a segmentation fault on the next code:

```
int situador(SDL_Surface * dib,struct sit_per per)
{

    SDL_Rect pos;
    struct sit_per * est;
    est=&per;


    while(est)
    {
        pos.x = est->ac->x;
        pos.y = est->ac->y;
        pos.w = est->ac->img[est->ac->dir]->w;
        pos.h = est->ac->img[est->ac->dir]->h;
        SDL_BlitSurface(est->ac->img[est->ac->dir], NULL, dib, &pos);
        est=est->si;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

dib variable comes from this function:

```
SDL_Surface * draw = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, ANCHO, ALTO, 24,rmask, gmask,bmask, amask);
```

The struct sit_per is the following:

```
struct sit_per
{
    struct personaje * ac;
    struct sit_per * si;
};

struct personaje
{
    char des[50];
    SDL_Surface * img[8];
    int dir;
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

And the img array was filled with the next function:

```
struct personaje * creador(char * cad)
{
    int x;
    struct personaje * per;

    per=(struct personaje *)malloc(sizeof(struct personaje));
    strcpy(per->des,cad);

    per->img[0] = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/andoni/SDL/img/flecha/0.bmp");
    per->img[1] = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/andoni/SDL/img/flecha/1.bmp");
    per->img[2] = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/andoni/SDL/img/flecha/2.bmp");
    per->img[3] = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/andoni/SDL/img/flecha/3.bmp");
    per->img[4] = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/andoni/SDL/img/flecha/4.bmp");
    per->img[5] = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/andoni/SDL/img/flecha/5.bmp");
    per->img[6] = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/andoni/SDL/img/flecha/6.bmp");
    per->img[7] = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/andoni/SDL/img/flecha/7.bmp");
    per->img[8] = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/andoni/SDL/img/flecha/8.bmp");

    for(x=0;x<9;x++)
        if(!per->img[x])
            x=10;
    if(x==10)
        return NULL;
    else
        return per;
}
```

I'm sure that the route to the images are well writed, and I can say that the x and y coordinates are well too.

I'll apreciate any suggestion, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably pass the second argument to `situador()` as a pointer rather than as a structure.  That is not directly related to the problem (seg fault) though.

Comment: can I give some advice, almost unrelated to the the question? 1) pass the pointer to the struct to situador, and so drop `est` and `est = &per`; 2) do not hard encode paths.

Comment: also modifying the variable of the loop to make the loop end, is not good! use break! and test for x < 9 to see if you've all images loaded or not! and in case of failure, it would be good to  free the struct per...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code loads 9 image pointers into an array of 8 elements.

This is not a recipe for happiness.

Comment: What he meant was... this is a recipe for overwriting `per->dir` ;)

Comment: That's It, I'm stupid, thank you very much. (5 mins until answer accepted)

Answer (score 1):

There are several oddness in your code.

First,

```
int situador(SDL_Surface * dib,struct sit_per per)
{
    SDL_Rect pos;
    struct sit_per * est;
    est=&per;
```

let it be

```
int situador(SDL_Surface * dib,struct sit_per *per)
{
    SDL_Rect pos;
    struct sit_per * est = per; // assignment can be made later
```

just style and avoiding too much data and copying on the stack.

The use of the for loop could be also an option;

```
  for(est = per; est != NULL; est = est->si)
```

If a function returns always a fixed value, you can make it return nothing...; so, `void situador(...)` instead of `int situador(...)`.

The function `creador` load 9 images, when only 8 are needed (one per direction, I suppose), this is the source for the segfault; do not hard encode (absolute) paths to files, as said before.

To exit a for loop, use the **break** keyword, avoid in general the modification of the loop variable (unless you have a good reason, and here I can't see one). Again, the for loop loops for 9 images, where you have room just for 8 in your array. If you need the 9th image, you have to write `SDL_Surface * img[9];`. It could be confusing, but when you declare an array, the number between brackets is the number of items, while when accessing, the index is 0-based so that the last element has index N-1.

So the whole final piece can become

```
for(x = 0; x < NUM_OF_ELEMENT; x++)
    if(!per->img[x])
        break;
if (x < NUM_OF_ELEMENT)
{
    int y;
    for(y = 0; y < x; y++)
       SDL_func_to_free_loaded_images(per->img[y]);
    free(per);
    return NULL;
}
else
    return per;
```

usually it is better to use named constants, instead of number; e.g.

```
#define  NUM_OF_ELEMENT 8
#define  NUM_OF_DES  50
```

and so

```
   struct personaje
   {
      char des[NUM_OF_DES];
      SDL_Surface * img[NUM_OF_ELEMENT];
      int dir;
      int x;
      int y;
   };
```

and so on... (of course you will pick another name, like NUM_OF_DIRS or NUM_OF_IMAGES or whatever is your meaningful prefered form in your language)

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions:

I need 9 directions, the movement directions and one to represent that no move is going to be done.

I will define some constants to manage number of elements, of course.

Bye!